# Flannel doesn't seem to be working while configuring a coreOS + kubernetes cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, kubernetes, coreos, etcd

I've installed coreOS baremetal on 4 PCs. I've set static IPs for all machines. I followed official coreOS [tutorial](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html) for coreOS + kubernetes.

Since I have a static network configuration and I'll have a multi-node etcd cluster, I've followed the following [tutorial](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/v2/clustering.html#static) for bootstrapping etcd. I've ran the script on all PCs and using `etcdctl member list` I see all nodes (PCs) are present in the etcd cluster.

Then I moved to step 2 (Deploy Kubernetes Master Node(s)) and I've followed the instructions step by step.

I've ran into the problem here:

```
curl -X PUT -d "value={\"Network\":\"$POD_NETWORK\",\"Backend\":{\"Type\":\"vxlan\"}}" "$ETCD_SERVER/v2/keys/coreos.com/network/config"
```

I've used the default `POD_NETWORK` (as stated in step 1) and one of `ETCD_ENDPOINTS` as `ETCD_SERVER`. However when I curl, the connection is established but I get the reply `404 page not found`.

I assume the problem is either in flannel or etcd (probably etcd). Even if I just `curl $ETCD_SERVER`, I get page not found. After a few days I'm at loss, I really don't know what could be wrong and how to fix it? If you need more info, please let me know. If you just point me in a right direciton so I can begin solving this problem, I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Edit:
I've found out If I `curl "${ETCD_SERVER}/version"` I get the correct reply (`{"etcdserver":"2.3.7","etcdcluster":"2.3.0"}`), if that helps.

**Update:**
I've found out the `CURL` didn't work, because I set the `ETCD_SERVER` to the wrong port (2380 instead of 2379). That works now. However, the flanneld service still doesn't start and it returns an error. `Job for flanneld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`
Here is the outpout of `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Subject: Unit flannel-docker-opts.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit flannel-docker-opts.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 08 08:43:26 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flannel-docker-opts.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 08 08:43:26 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flannel-docker-opts.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 08 08:43:30 kubernetes-4 sudo[27594]:      kub : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/kub ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start flanneld
Mar 08 08:43:30 kubernetes-4 sudo[27594]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by kub(uid=0)
Mar 08 08:43:30 kubernetes-4 sudo[27594]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: Stopped flannel - Network fabric for containers (System Application Container).
-- Subject: Unit flanneld.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit flanneld.service has finished shutting down.
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: Starting flannel - Network fabric for containers (System Application Container)...
-- Subject: Unit flanneld.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit flanneld.service has begun starting up.
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 rkt[27608]: rm: unable to resolve UUID from file: open /var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper.uuid: no such file or directory
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 rkt[27608]: rm: failed to remove one or more pods
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 flannel-wrapper[27625]: + exec /usr/bin/rkt run --uuid-file-save=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper.uuid --trust-keys-from-https --mount volume=notify,target=/run/systemd/notify 
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 flannel-wrapper[27625]: run: discovery failed
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=254/n/a
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 rkt[27652]: stop: unable to resolve UUID from file: open /var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper.uuid: no such file or directory
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: Failed to start flannel - Network fabric for containers (System Application Container).
-- Subject: Unit flanneld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit flanneld.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 sudo[27594]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: Starting flannel docker export service - Network fabric for containers (System Application Container)...
-- Subject: Unit flannel-docker-opts.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit flannel-docker-opts.service has begun starting up.
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 rkt[27659]: rm: unable to resolve UUID from file: open /var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper2.uuid: no such file or directory
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 rkt[27659]: rm: failed to remove one or more pods
Mar 08 08:43:36 kubernetes-4 flannel-wrapper[27674]: + exec /usr/bin/rkt run --uuid-file-save=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper2.uuid --trust-keys-from-https --net=host --volume run-flannel,kind=host,source
Mar 08 08:43:38 kubernetes-4 flannel-wrapper[27674]: run: discovery failed
Mar 08 08:43:38 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flannel-docker-opts.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=254/n/a
Mar 08 08:43:38 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: Failed to start flannel docker export service - Network fabric for containers (System Application Container).
-- Subject: Unit flannel-docker-opts.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit flannel-docker-opts.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 08 08:43:38 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flannel-docker-opts.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 08 08:43:38 kubernetes-4 systemd[1]: flannel-docker-opts.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 08 08:43:39 kubernetes-4 sudo[27708]:      kub : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/kub ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Mar 08 08:43:39 kubernetes-4 sudo[27708]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by kub(uid=0)
Mar 08 08:43:39 kubernetes-4 sudo[27708]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
```

**Update 2:** (added `systemctl` output for flanneld and flannel-docker-opts service)

`systemctl cat flannel-docker-opts` output:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/flannel-docker-opts.service
[Unit]
Description=flannel docker export service - Network fabric for containers (System Application Container)
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos/flannel
PartOf=flanneld.service
Before=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=60

Environment="FLANNEL_IMAGE_TAG=v0.6.2"
Environment="RKT_RUN_ARGS=--uuid-file-save=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper2.uuid"
Environment="FLANNEL_IMAGE_ARGS=--exec=/opt/bin/mk-docker-opts.sh"

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper2.uuid
ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper -d /run/flannel/flannel_docker_opts.env -i
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/rkt stop --uuid-file=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper2.uuid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`systemctl cat flanneld` output:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/flanneld.service
[Unit]
Description=flannel - Network fabric for containers (System Application Container)
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos/flannel
After=etcd.service etcd2.service etcd-member.service
Before=docker.service flannel-docker-opts.service
Requires=flannel-docker-opts.service

[Service]
Type=notify
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
LimitNOFILE=40000
LimitNPROC=1048576

Environment="FLANNEL_IMAGE_TAG=v0.6.2"
Environment="FLANNEL_OPTS=--ip-masq=true"
Environment="RKT_RUN_ARGS=--uuid-file-save=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper.uuid"
EnvironmentFile=-/run/flannel/options.env

ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe ip_tables
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir --parents /var/lib/coreos /run/flannel
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper.uuid
ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper $FLANNEL_OPTS
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/rkt stop --uuid-file=/var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper.uuid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/flanneld.service.d/40-ExecStartPre-symlink.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/ln -sf /etc/flannel/options.env /run/flannel/options.env
```

**Update 3:**
Using `journalctl` -xer I get a new error, if this is helpful:

```
Mar 09 08:39:15 kubernetes-4 locksmithd[1147]: Unlocking old locks failed: [etcd.service etcd2.service] are inactive. Retrying in 5m0s.
Mar 09 08:39:15 kubernetes-4 locksmithd[1147]: [etcd.service etcd2.service] are inactive
```

Comment: Can you post the output of your `curl` command, if possible with the `-i` flag to include the response headers?

Comment: @AntoineCotten the curl now went through, but I still can't start flanneld (see my update)

Comment: The error messages are not helpful unfortunately, could you add the output of `systemctl cat <unit name>` for flannel-docker-opts and flanneld?

Comment: @AntoineCotten added

Comment: Looks like you'll have to add the `--debug` flag to the `FLANNEL_IMAGE_ARGS` environment variable, in both units. I've got the feeling `journalct -xe` is suppressing the interesting parts of the output.

Comment: @AntoineCotten I am having trouble editing the flannel-docker-opts.service file. I can't write to it even though I edit it as root. Will let you know when I figure it out.

Comment: Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing the file?  You could also use a systemd drop-in.

Comment: @AntoineCotten I can't modify it, so I'll try with a drop-in now. Is this syntax correct for using a debug flag?

`Environment="FLANNEL_IMAGE_ARGS=--exec--debug=/opt/bin/mk-docker-opts.sh"`

Comment: The flag should rather be at the very end, not appended to the --exec flag

Comment: @AntoineCotten I've added --debug with a drop-in, but journalctl still has the same output

Comment: Typical problem with journald. Maybe you can try to search your last logs with `journalctl -r`, otherwise you will have to export the variables from the unit in your current shell and run the ExecStart command manually in order to see the error messages.

Comment: @AntoineCotten I've got another error using `journalctl -r` (see my update). If that's not helpful, I'll also try to run `ExecStart` command

Comment: Locksmithd is something else, just drop the -x and -e flags. The conversation is getting too huge, we should start a chat instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137647/discussion-between-mythic-and-antoine-cotten).

Answer (score 0):

From one of the Etcd nodes, or any of the nodes if you are unning Etcd in proxy-mode on them. Try to use the `etcdctl` binary included in CoreOS to find out cluster health:

```
etcdctl cluster-health
```

should show something like:

```
member ce2a822cea30bfca is healthy: got healthy result from http://10.129.69.201:2379
cluster is healthy
```

Try also:

```
etcdctl set /coreos.com/network/config '{"Network":"$POD_NETWORK", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
```

Comment: Every member and cluster is healthy. The problem lies elsewhere. Check my update, please